# What are some feature rich Visual Web GUI data grid control options?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, datagridview, controls, visual-web-gui

I'm looking for a Data Grid View control compatible with Gizmox's Visual Web GUI that is on the level of Telerik's RAD Grid, or YUI's Data Grid.  The stock Data Grid is lacking in the functionality that I require unfortunately.  I'm using VWG 6.4.  I know that I can wrap controls for use in VWG, but have not attempted it since 6.4's release.  I had tried in the past to wrap Telerik's RAD Grid, but never got it work properly.  And obviously I would prefer to develop for the grid in a stateful manner like any other VWG control if at all possible, so an extension of the stock data grid view, or a custom VWG based control would be the best option if it exists.

I was really hoping that Gizmox's Professional Controls Suite would have a rich Data Grid control, but it doesn't appear that it will.

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of the new ListView and some custom controls will do wonderfully for me in most any case that I can think of.

Based on this post in the Gizmox forum:
http://www.visualwebgui.com/Developers/Forums/tabid/364/forumid/25/threadid/35522/scope/posts/threadpage/1/Default.aspx

So far 6.4 has resolved every issue I had with VWG in the past, I am really looking forward to getting started on the UI for my project.